# How to extract data from website?

Tags: android, database, jsp, web-scraping

I want to create an Android App in which student can see their attendance. Actually attendance is updated daily in website as a database. In the website homepage student must enter their log in details such as Username, password and captcha. Then their profile is displayed in which their attendance can be seen. I want to extract the data alone (that is attendance percentage). I think the website uses .asp database. Anybody just give me an idea!
Also sorry if my question doesn't sounds good...

Comment: Actually it is possible or not??

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver?

Comment: @clapas : Yes I have access to web server by my log in id and password

Comment: And the database credentials?

Comment: @clapas no i dont have database credentials...It is necessary to have

Comment: You need either a database account or an administrator account for the web application, in order to fetch the data you need.

Comment: @clapas how to get database account...am I need to get permission from website owner??

Comment: You need to talk to the the server administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say, you are saving in `DB`, you mean you are saving in `SQL Server` DB or any other `DB` and your web App reads DB displays data. So definitely you can develop an android App to interact with that `DB` and show values in that App.

Comment: You can check the asp.net code and see if that saves in `DB`. FYI - you have tagged this question in `database`, so you must be using that.

Comment: actually there is a javascript option "Attendance". If I move the mouse over the text "Attendance" url "javascript:somefunction(7)" is displayed...now after clicking attendance I can see the databases of subjects and their respective percentages..

Comment: So my point was that, if it uses any `DB`, then you are good to develop android App and that can display attendance. Whether asp.net App does have `DB`, for that you need to post the code or share the code with me , so that i can tell the answer

Comment: Does the values or the information persists , when you visit the asp.net site multiple times from multiple browsers?

Comment: Bro Shall I give the website link and login details

Comment: Yes that will do the job for now, but if you can look through code to see, if that saves in DB , that will be more helpful, for e.g see web.config, check if it has `ConnectionString` , if yes, get that `name`, search in code  etc.

Comment: Since you told that `student must enter their log in details such as Username, password`, that mean data is stored somewhere and gets validated, so there should a `DB` behind this, only thing is that, you need to check where is `DB` and start developing android APP to interact with DB.

Comment: yeah I got you bro...but I cant find out DB

Comment: Yes, you tagged this question incorrectly, it is `JSP`, java based application and hosted in `apache`. To conclude you can develop android app. I have checked that it uses nice handling of data, using some `api` kind of thing, which can be reusable in android app.

Comment: Bro Am i able to extract the data or not

Comment: Yes , you can extract data using `api` , which data you need, i mean which option after looking in will give required data?

Comment: Which api bro??is there any tutoial to use that

Comment: I can't explain any more, you need to consult anyone who knows how to check/debug using chrome->network or firebug or fiddler, to get api url . Regarding Db credential - you need to consult with the person who has written this `api` , i can see that, he/she has implemented some authentication for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could download data from particular user in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends!** Try to analyse the website, How credentials are verifying and interacting with the database. **Firebug** is a good browser plugin to do so. For achieving the purpose you need to make a script which will take the username, password and capcha to the database and after return you the attendance page.The most hard part is to reading capcha. **[here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189455/how-can-robots-beat-captchas)** is good discussion over it.

Once you get the page you can scrap the page through beautiful Library called **[JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/)** in java. It is quite easy to learn. After getting the desired value after parsing, you can show the data as you want to show in your app.

Second option can be you anylyse the website extract that **div** which has the Credential thing and show only that div in webview, WebView has options to **change** UI element such as background and fonts. After successful Login and getting the result page, parse the information of your use and show the result as you want.

Lastly -The lazy way to do thing by using WebView for whole app. so every thing in webview after changing the UI. It will be same but with different look.

Comment: The site is of JSP and hosted in apache..can I able to extract data from those type

Comment: Yes it is possible... Give it a try with firebug. Check how credential works with site... Also You have second option I discussed that will 100% work.

Comment: Best way to say thank on stackoverflow is to upvote the answer ;) But I am glad that you find me helpful Buddy :)

Comment: function getStudentDetails(arg){                       urlNew="../resource/StudentDetailsResources.jsp?resourceid="+arg; document.getElementById('errmsg').style.display="none";
                        GetAjaxTemplates(urlNew,'form01');
                        
                        }